# Setup for Gmail in Emacs VM

Tags: email, emacs, gmail

after using mutt as an email client for a while, I would like to try the VM package of GNU Emacs (if it is important: Ubuntu 11.04, 64bit) to read my mail.
I "googled" the web if there is a configuration file available (modifications necessary in .emacs and the new .vm file) from which I can easily start my own customizations (I want to use my gmail account with IMAP support).

Maybe someone has such files and can provide them (similar to the many "dot-emacs" files)?

Answer (score 1):

use `gnus gmail`

Put the following in your `~/.gnus` file and replace `“user@gmail.com”` with your email address:

```
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "gmail"
           (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
           (nnimap-server-port 993)
           (nnimap-stream ssl)))

(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587
                   "user@gmail.com" nil))
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      gnus-ignored-newsgroups "^to\\.\\|^[0-9. ]+\\( \\|$\\)\\|^[\"]\"[#'()]")
```

Put the following in your `~/.authinfo` file and replace `“user@gmail.com”` with your email address and replace `“secret”` with your `password`—or your application-specific password:

```
machine imap.gmail.com login user@gmail.com password secret port 993
machine smtp.gmail.com login user@gmail.com password secret port 587
```

When sending your first email from gnus, you might get a `STARTTLS` error. If you’re using `homebrew` in Mac OS X, you can install the necessary package with brew install `gnutls`.

You can find more information in the following sections.

Run <kbd>M-x gnus</kbd> and enjoy.