# Setting up Emacs Rmail with Gmail

Tags: email, emacs, gmail

I am trying to set up Rmail to work with my Gmail account but so far have not been able to figure out how to set it up. Could someone give a brief explanation/tutorial on how to set it up or at least give a link to one?

Comment: Have you tried Googling all three of these keywords at the same time: **emacs rmail gmail**  Did you already look at the following thread and the links cited therein?:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20979918/2112489

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't see anything about how to set up Rmail. They are mostly for other programs such as Gnus and Wanderlust.

Answer (score 2):

RMail has no direct support of IMAP protocols.
However, it can use `movemail`; See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Movemail.html#Movemail for details.

You can do POP, and there are instructions given (for all three native possibilities in Emacs).
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GettingMail

I hope that helps.

All the best,

Albert