# Synchronise and read Gmail offline, using isync OR offlineimap

Tags: ssl-certificate, gmail-imap, mu

My goal is to sync my emails from a Gmail account and index them to search and read within Emacs. The latter is not yet relevant as I cannot get the emails to sync to my laptop.

I am running Mavericks and so working in Mac Terminal.

I have followed [SO accepted answer and the answer in the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979918/reading-email-from-gmail-in-emacs-24) trying to use *offlineimap*, as well as a second method in [this (more promising) tutorial on using *isync*](http://www.ict4g.net/adolfo/notes/2014/12/27/EmacsIMAP.html) (and so *mbsync*). Both ways end up using **mu** and the interface for Emacs: **mu4e**.

The certificates are not being read/interpreted correctly. I do not know why as I do not understand the error messages. Here is the one from *offlineimap* :

```
> OfflineIMAP 6.5.7
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
Account sync Gmail:
 *** Processing account Gmail
 Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993
 PLAIN authentication failed: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
 LOGIN authentication failed: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
 ERROR: All authentication types failed:
    PLAIN: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    LOGIN: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
 *** Finished account 'Gmail' in 0:01
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: All authentication types failed:
    PLAIN: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    LOGIN: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
> 
> Traceback:   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7/libexec/offlineimap/accounts.py",
> line 263, in syncrunner
>     self.__sync()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7/libexec/offlineimap/accounts.py",
> line 326, in __sync
>     remoterepos.getfolders()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7/libexec/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py",
> line 351, in getfolders
>     imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7/libexec/offlineimap/imapserver.py",
> line 451, in acquireconnection
>     self.__authn_helper(imapobj)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7/libexec/offlineimap/imapserver.py",
> line 366, in __authn_helper
>     "failed:\n\t%s"% msg, OfflineImapError.ERROR.REPO)
```

Here is the one from *mbsync*:

```
> C: 0/3  B: 0/2  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
Error while loading certificate file '/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/Equifax.crt': error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
C: 3/3  B: 0/2  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
```

I have installed everything with Homebrew and am using the folders as per the tutorials. The problem is coming from the certificates, but I don't know what the problem could be. I have the setting within Gmail to allow IMAP and also allowed connection for less secure apps.

How might I deal with the certificates differently?

Comment: were you able to make it work. I too get the same issue with mbsync.

Comment: I didn't get things working as I would've liked, so gave up. Once I had certificates all sorted, it either didn't sync or synced absolutely everything (so ~15Gb of emails and attachments). I have been using plain `gnus` instead, which works pretty well and has many features. If @brariden solution below doesn't work for you, I'd recommend stickng with gnus, where I managed to eaily set up encryption, and other useful things like `yas-templates`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the offlineimap error, Google is complaining that you aren't using Oauth2.  I got past the same offlineimap issue following the explanation here: https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/issues/228

You need to configure your `.offlineimaprc` to use Oauth2 instead of specifying a username/password.  Here's the template and instructions on how to generate the tokens:
https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap.conf#L764

Here's the important settings:

```
auth_mechanisms = GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, XOAUTH2, PLAIN, LOGIN
oauth2_client_secret = ...
oauth2_client_id = ...
oauth2_refresh_token = ...
```